# How much more efficient is Java Google App Engine in threadsafe mode?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Java Google App Engine you can turn on Concurrent Requests / Threadsafe mode: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests

The only reason to do this is that the Google servers will need to spin up fewer instances of your app to serve a given number of requests and therefore potentially save you money.  Of course doing this will also mean you will have to write threadsafe code.

So the interesting question is: how much money does this tend to save?  Has anyone attempted to measure it under some benchmark configuration / application functionality / load ?

Comment: Hello. I have published an analysis of threadsafe for GAE here devcon5.blogspot.com (although for GAE/J) and would very much appreciate any comments or additional questions I should cover. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your code:

1. In single request mode, you can easily calculate requests per second: if a request on average takes 100ms to finish, then one instance will be able to perform 10 requests per second.
2. In concurrent request mode this is depends on two factors:

   A. The type of instance you are using - AFAIK they are all the same you just get different number of cores. More cores means higher concurrent performance.

   B. The ratio of CPU-bound code versus IO-bound code a request is performing. If your code is more IO-bound (= waiting for Datastore or other external service) then CPU will be able to run more of it in parallel.

In my app I see 15-20 rps at 200ms per request on the basic instance, so I could say that the factor between single-request and multi-request mode is about 3-4.